# Callback URL of autodesk firgew is not working for virtual server

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am very new (you can call me a noob) to web apps or web development.

I tried using one of the source codes available at [Forge Platform](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge). It is working fine with `localhost:3000.`

Then I decided to host it on our company's local server for everyone. But is unable to redirect to the specified callback URL.

I tried entering the callback URL inside the code also as an env variable.

**Please help me fix why it is not working from the local server.?**

[image: java script page wioth callback url] [image: Call back url with local server IP saved in the Autodesk aps.]
[image: Webpage]
[image: error: Unable to redirect]

Comment: Are you able to access the server from public network? It will not work if the local server can not be accessed from outside.

Comment: My plan is to deploy the web app for an internal team. So I didn't check with the public network. I think it is not accessible from the outside. Are you sure this is causing an error while redirecting to callback URL? However, the same script/web app is working for me on localhost:3000 (from company premises), it is redirecting properly.

Comment: Checked with my colleague, could you please check if you can access the callback endpoint on your machine, if Yes, then the callback should work.

Comment: Hi Zhong Wu, Actually I am very new to this concept. What do you mean by "access callback endpoint on your machine" means? Should I type "http://172.17.121.33:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth" in the browser and check? (However, I tried, and it is not working. error: "page not found")

Comment: this is a POST request, can you use Postman to do a POST request with the endpoint to see what respose?